# Overriding IOS UIButton buttonPressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uikit

I have an ViewController.m file as such from viewDidLoad:

```
_registerButton = [AuthButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[_registerButton setTitle:@"Register" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_registerButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.screenWidth / 2.0 - 1.0, 60.0);

[_registerButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

...

 (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //sentder.titleLabel
    [sender setTitle:@"Registers" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

registerButton is an AuthButton declared via a property.  How do I override buttonPressed and move my IBAction code to my AuthButton.m class? Confused on the syntax (new to objective-c).

Comment: For this, you have to use protocols.

Comment: Check this:- http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html

Comment: why not just declare target as your AuthButton?
smth like: [_registerButton addTarget:_registerButton action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: you mean within the view controller? I was trying to make it more oo

Comment: I mean you don't need IBAction at all. "addTarget:object" object there is a class which will be responsible for handling button pressing events.  Just set target that you need and implement "buttonPressed" method there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `addTarget` attribute is what you need. In your example the target is `self` and hence the button press event looks for the selector in the current object.

If you change the target to the instance of `AuthButton`, and write a corresponding selector in `AuthButton.m` you should be good.